# Reading Properties file in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to put dynamic value in the argument of ConfigSlurper(String env) but it is displaying no value, it displays value only when I pass the string constant as env in ConfigSlurper.

```
Ex: 
def config = new ConfigSlurper('PRODUCT').parse(propertiesFile)
println "PRODUCT_NAME: "+config.PRODUCT_NAME
```

o/p:

```
PRODUCT_NAME: TYPEB_Routing,TYPEB_Mediation,TYPEX_Routing,TYPEX_Mediation
```

But when I try to read property file by using dynamic value in env I'm getting:

```
Ex: 
def pdt1 = "PRODUCT"
def config = new ConfigSlurper('$pdt1').parse(propertiesFile)
println "PRODUCT_NAME: "+config.PRODUCT_NAME
```

o/p:

```
 PRODUCT_NAME: [:]
```

Why this is happening, I'm not getting??
Please Explain....

Comment: Do we have to guess what the file looks like?

Comment: @user3666156 : Could you edit the question to include the sample file you are parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using double quotes on the interpolated string, like this:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper("${pdt1}").parse(propertiesFile)
```

Single quoted strings don't support interpolation.

Here's the documentation on the syntax. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation

Comment: This works, so +1.. OP needs to tell more about his config file to make any more progress.

Answer (score 0):

`'$pdt1'` definitely won't work `'` does not evaluate `GString` so the value passed will be `$pdt1` literally. You need to use `"` - double quotes.

Maybe you also need to pass `"$pdt1".toString()` - convert the argument to `String` explicitly.